# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: VS403417: ChangedBy value cannot be empty when BypassRules is specified

Tags: azure-devops, vsts-sync-migrator

Error: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.UnexpectedErrorException: There is a problem on the server. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: VS403417: ChangedBy value cannot be empty when BypassRules is specified

I am using the latest version 12.0.3. Json file below.

{

```
    "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
    "Source": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/",
    "Project": "AS-SYSS-RequirementStudio-CMMI",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "RequirementStudioRefID",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
    "AreaPath": "Area",
    "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
    },
    "Target": {
    "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
    "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/",
    "Project": "AS-SYSS-RequirementStudio-Library",
    "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "RequirementStudioRefID",
    "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    "PersonalAccessToken": "",
    "LanguageMaps": {
    "AreaPath": "Area",
    "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    }
    },
    "FieldMaps": [
    {
    "$type": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2"
    },
    "targetFieldsAndValues": {
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2"
    }
    },
    {
    "$type": "FieldBlankMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "targetField": "TfsMigrationTool.ReflectedWorkItemId"
    },
    {
    "$type": "FieldValueMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "System.State",
    "targetField": "System.State",
    "defaultValue": "New",
    "valueMapping": {
    "Approved": "Approved",
    "New": "New",
    "Committed": "Committed",
    "In Progress": "In Progress",
    "To Do": "To Do",
    "Done": "Done",
    "Removed": "Removed",
    "Proposed" : "Proposed",
    "Active" : "Active",
    "Resolved" :"Resolved",
    "Closed" : "Closed",
    "Completed" : "Completed",
    "Ready To Start" : "Ready To Start",
    "Detailed Design and Configuration" : "Detailed Design and Configuration",
    "Ready For Design Review" : "Ready For Design Review",
    "In Build" : "In Build",
    "Ready For Test" : "Ready For Test",
    "Internal test" : "Internal test",
    "Ready for Customer Witnessed Test (FAT / UAT)" : "Ready for Customer Witnessed Test (FAT / UAT)",
    "Customer Approved" : "Customer Approved",
    "Cancelled" : "Cancelled",
    "Customer Approval" : "Customer Approval",
    "Customer Acceptance" : "Customer Acceptance",
    "In Active" : "In Active",
    "In Planning" : "In Planning"
    }
    },
    {
    "$type": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority",
    "targetField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank",
    "defaultValue": null
    },
    {
    "$type": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
    "SourceToTargetMappings": {
    "SourceField1": "TargetField1",
    "SourceField2": "TargetField2"
    }
    },
    
    {
    "$type": "FieldMergeMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField1": "System.Description",
    "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
    "sourceField3": null,
    "targetField": "System.Description",
    "formatExpression": "{0}
    
    
    Acceptance Criteria
    {1}",
    "doneMatch": "##DONE##"
    },
    {
    "$type": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "COMPANY.PRODUCT.Release",
    "targetField": "COMPANY.DEVISION.MinorReleaseVersion",
    "pattern": "PRODUCT \d{4}.(\d{1})",
    "replacement": "$1"
    },
    {
    "$type": "FieldValuetoTagMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked",
    "pattern": "Yes",
    "formatExpression": "{0}"
    },
    {
    "$type": "TreeToTagMapConfig",
    "WorkItemTypeName": "",
    "toSkip": 6,
    "timeTravel": 1
    }
    ],
    "GitRepoMapping": null,
    "LogLevel": "Information",
    "CommonEnrichersConfig": null,
    "Processors": [
    {
    "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
    "Enabled": true,
    "ReplayRevisions": true,
    "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
    "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
    "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
    "WIQLQueryBit": "AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Bug','Change Request', 'CM_EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块', 'Diagram', 'Document', 'Feature', 'Note', 'Requirement', 'Review', 'Risk', 'S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE', 'S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE Instance','S88_CM_INTERLOCK PERMISSIVE FORCE SP','S88_EM_ EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块', 'S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE CLASS', 'S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE COMMAND', 'S88_PC_PROCESS CELL', 'S88_PL_PLANT LEVEL', 'Mockup', 'S88_SA_SITE AREA', 'S88_UM_UNIT MODULE', 'Section', 'Task', 'Test Case', 'User Story', 'Coversation')",
    "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
    "LinkMigration": true,
    "AttachmentMigration": true,
    "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\temp\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\",
    "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
    "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
    "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
    "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
    "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
    "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
    "AttachRevisionHistory": false,
    "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
    "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
    "WorkItemIDs": null,
    "MaxRevisions": 0,
    "NodeStructureEnricherEnabled": null,
    "UseCommonNodeStructureEnricherConfig": false,
    "NodeBasePaths": [
    //"Product\Area\Path1",
    //"Product\Area\Path2"
    ],
    "AreaMaps": {},
    "IterationMaps": {}
    }
    ],
    "Version": "12.0",
    "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
    "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
    "Bug": "Bug",
    "Change Request" : "Change Request",
    "CM_EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块" : "CM_EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块",
    "Coversation" : "Coversation",
    "Mockup" : "Mockup",
    "Diagram" :"Diagram",
    "Document" : "Document",
    "Feature" : "Feature",
    "Feedback Request" : "Feedback Request",
    "Note" : "Note",
    "Review" : "Review",
    "Risk" : "Risk",
    "S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE" : "S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE",
    "S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE Instance" : "S88_ CM_CONTROL MODULE Instance",
    "Requirement" : "Requirement",
    "S88_CM_INTERLOCK PERMISSIVE FORCE SP" : "S88_CM_INTERLOCK PERMISSIVE FORCE SP",
    "S88_EM_ EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块" : "S88_EM_ EQUIPMENT MODEL_设备模块",
    "S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE CLASS" : "S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE CLASS",
    "S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE COMMAND" : "S88_EM_EQUIPMENT MODULE COMMAND",
    "S88_PC_PROCESS CELL" : "S88_PC_PROCESS CELL",
    "S88_PL_PLANT LEVEL" : "S88_PL_PLANT LEVEL",
    "S88_SA_SITE AREA" : "S88_SA_SITE AREA",
    "S88_UM_UNIT MODULE" : "S88_UM_UNIT MODULE",
    "Section" : "Section",
    "Task" : "Task",
    "Test Case" : "Test Case",
    "User Story" : "User Story"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
    "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
    {
    "Name": "Source",
    "EndpointEnrichers": null
    },
    {
    "Name": "Target",
    "EndpointEnrichers": null
    }
    ]
    }
    }`
```

Note: I was trying to migrate the workitems with in the org. the the situation is that the migration is between two project along with same process.

Comment: What is the source instance? TFS 2010 / Azure DevOps server 2019?

Comment: This field is only empty in the save if it is empty I the Source or it is set to empty with a field map.

Comment: Hello Martin,  I am using the Azure Devops Services and I am doing the migration between two project with in the same organization with same process.

Comment: This field is only empty in the save if it is empty I the Source or it is set to empty with a field map :  not understood this comment, could you please elaborate more on this.